# What is the name of the font in this "Calypso Cocktail" logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I want to recreate this logo and I need the name of the font.

Comment: Hi Obinna, we have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1083/19174) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question with the relevant information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Calypso` is lettering and not a font. A Din type of font will come close to what you need, but I would use a pen tool and trace it.

`Cocktail` is Helvetica

Comment: Specifically, the slightly condensed [DIN 1451 EngSchrift](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/din-1451/engschrift) would be a good starting point. Otherwise good call.